# deep copy of non eigen float* to eigen::MatrixXf

Tags: c++, eigen

if `x` is a non-eigen vector of floats, i can map it to an `eigen::MatrixXf` by:

```
MatrixXf x_cen=Map<MatrixXf>(*x,*n,*p);
```

But then, modifications to `x_cen` will be reported to `x` as well since they are sharing the memory. What i want is to avoid this. I'd like to deep copy `x` unto an `eigen::MatrixXf` `x_cen` in order to ensure that changes made to `x_cen` are not reported to `x`. How can that 
be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code:

```
MatrixXf x_cen=Map<MatrixXf>(*x,*n,*p);
```

is already doing a deep copy! So you're good. There is no shallow copies in Eigen.

Just for completeness, one can name a `Map<>` object to use it like a `MatrixXf`:

```
Map<MatrixXf> x_cen(*x,*n,*p);
```

In this case, and only in this case, modifications to `x_cen` will be reported to `x`.